# how to change a popup window's font in angular 4?

Tags: html, angular, popupwindow

I'm using angular and i have a popup window to print a page. here is the code in my component.ts:

```
 headContents = document.getElementById('head-section').innerHTML;
innerContents = document.getElementById('inner-section').innerHTML;
signContents = document.getElementById('sign-section').innerHTML;
popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=auto,width=auto');
// console.log(popupWin)
popupWin.document.open();
popupWin.document.write(
  '<html><head><style> body{width: ' + this.width + '; height: ' + this.height + ';}' +
  '.head{padding-left: ' + this.date_padding_left + '; padding-right: ' + this.date_padding_right + '; padding-top: ' + this.date_padding_top + ' ; padding-bottom: ' + this.date_padding_bottom + '; direction: rtl} ' +
  '.inner{padding-left: ' + this.text_padding_left + '; padding-right: ' + this.text_padding_right + '; padding-top: ' + this.text_padding_top + '; padding-bottom: ' + this.text_padding_bottom + '; text-align: justify; direction: ' + this.rtl + ';white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;width: 166mm;max-height: 873px} ' +
  '.sign{padding-left: ' + this.sign_padding_left + '; padding-right: ' + this.sign_padding_right + '}</style>' +
  '</head><body onload="window.print();window.close()"><p class="head">' + headContents + '</p> <p class="inner">' + innerContents + '</p> <p class="sign">' + signContents + '</p></body></html>');
popupWin.document.close();
```

now i want to change the .inner class font. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've just tried this and it seems to be working. So, now your ts file should look something like this (making sure to place your font file in the src/assets folder):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   title = 'app';
   headContents = "Header";
   innerContents = "Contents pending...";
   signContents = "Signs, signs, Everywhere signs!";

   showWin()
   {
      let popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=auto,width=auto');

      popupWin.document.open();
      popupWin.document.write('<html><head><style>'+
      '@font-face {font-family:myFont;src:url("assets/Pacifico.ttf");}'+
      '.inner{font-family: myFont;font-size: 40pt;text-align: justify;}'+
      '</style></head><body onload="window.print();window.close()"><p class="head">' + this.headContents + '</p> <p class="inner">' + this.innerContents + '</p> <p class="sign">' + this.signContents + '</p></body></html>');
      popupWin.document.close();
   }
}
```

And your html file should have something like this:

```
<button (click)="showWin()">Show Window</button>
```

On a side note, you may want to use a binding to get values from the HTML file instead of using *document.getElementById()*

Comment: i have another problem, i'm using two language (english and arabic) but font-family in this part doesn't work for arabic texts! in my scss file i  wrote a font-face and call the arabic fonts but i don't know how to do it here? @tiki

Comment: Okay, just edited the code. Like I mentioned above, you'll need to place you font file in the `src/assets` folder for the code to work. If this was the solution you were looking for, could you mark it as the answer and up vote it please. Much appreciated. Thanks